# Why doesn't my 'back' button work after visiting this website?

Tags: browser, website

Why doesn't my 'back' button work after visiting [this](http://www.johnsmithjohnsmith.com) website? I have seen many sites where you have to click the back button twice in order to get back to where you were, but I have never seen one where you can't get 'back' at all. What have the site builders done?

Comment: Excuse me if *don't* click on the link you provided.

Comment: Feel free... I can understand your concerns... though I'm pretty sure the site builders were simply over-enthusiastic rather than devious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd assume it's a bit of javascript code that is preventing you from going back, using `history.forward()`. All `history.forward()` does when called is bounce you forward in your browser history, which is what this website seems to be doing. Although if you click repeatedly fast enough (3 fingers on the mouse type of deal), you can :)

Comment: Maybe easier is to right-click on the back button. Most browsers will show a history of your visited pages, and you can choose the first one that isn't on the problematic site.